# Is there a trick to pass a file descriptor to another process?

Tags: linux, kernel, device

Here is my trouble.

Facts:

```
1. There is a device placed in /dev/xxx. 
   All files under /dev/ should have permission of 700 
   (root permission only accessible. No ownership change and group setting)

2. Not-root user application 'A' needs to open /dev/xxx and 
   perform ioctl on the FD.
```

I've come to think several options:

```
option 1) Write a stub application 'X' that can run with root. 
          Open /dev/xxx in 'X' and perform IPC between A and X.
```

This option is not actually a good one due to the IPC overhead, because A needs to do ioctl extremely frequently.

```
option 2) Change the location of /dev/xxx into some other place like
          /data/xxx where /data/ is accessible by 'A'
```

For some reason, if I try to open this /data/xxx with valid persmission, the open function returns permission denied error. I don't understand why this happens. Is there some additional protection by kernel for opening device file in some place else in /dev?

```
option 3) Write a stub application 'X' that can run with root.
          Open /dev/xxx in 'X' and pass the FD to 'A'.
```

I'm not sure this is a plausible option. I hope if you could give any comments on this option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you can run a process as root, then the thing to do is, open the file, then call setuid to change to the unpriv'd user and do everything you need to do. I've done this under BSD, but there's no guarantee that whatever device driver you're messing with isn't going to look at your process' user ID and freak out because it's no longer root.